# Junit fail method is not functioning as expected

Tags: eclipse, junit, seetest

I'm writing junit unit testcases with seetest tool. But i'm not able to use the fail function appropriately.

Even if i give fail() for a particular condition, my junit case still executes it as pass.

Here is my code:

```
client.setDevice("ios_app:iPhonel");
           client.launch("com.netsnapper.connect.Netsnapper-Connect", true, false);
           client.sleep(10000);
           client.click("default", "Logoutmenu", 0, 1);
           client.click("default", "About", 0, 1);
           String version = client.getTextIn("default", "version", 0, "NATIVE", "Inside", 560, 42);
           if((client.isElementFound("TEXT", "Key Features", 0)) && !(version != null && !version.isEmpty())){
              fail("failed");
           }
```

Even if the condition is satisified, it still shows as pass.